# How to send emails from an address without logging into the server

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm building an asp.net application for a client that requires a confirmation email to be sent. I've gotten the code working but the only problem is that I can't get the code to work with their web host (godaddy). Is there a way to send emails with the from address marked as the clients' without having to use godaddy? (essentially faking it)

Answer (score 0):

Be careful or you'll lose your emails to spam filters.

Specifically, see the Reverse PTR record discussion here:

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/04/so-youd-like-to-send-some-email-through-code.html